# .show() buttons appear before the everything else

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, show

I am using jQuery's .show() function to show a popup when the user presses the delete button.

the code is working flawlessly except for one thing.  The two buttons appear before the rest of the div and the text appears.  Does anyone know why or if there is a fix for this?

HTML (#delete is nested elsewhere)

```
<div id="popupbgitembg">
<ul class="popupbgitems">
        <li>
            Are you sure you want to delete?
        </li> 
        <li></li> 
        <li>
            <asp:Button ID="butdelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Font-Size="11px"/>
            <asp:Button ID="butcancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Font-Size="11px"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
        function popup() {
            $("#popupbg").animate({ opacity: ".8" });
            $("#delete").click(
            function() {
                $("#popupbg, #popupbgitembg").show('fast')
            });
            $("#butdelete, #butcancel").click(
            function() {
                $("#popupbg, #popupbgitembg").hide('medium')
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot & css for reference ?

Answer (score 0):

My Guess is it has to do with the buttons being asp controls. Why don't you hide the buttons and display them once the dialog is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing asp-buttons with html-buttons , 
if that did not help :i am not understanding what is #popupbg refering to 
if it ia nesteddiv in that case just use:

```
//first change

    <li>
        <button type="button" ID="butdelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Font-Size="11px"/>
        <button type="button" ID="butcancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Font-Size="11px"/>
    </li>
```

// second change

```
        function() {
            $("#popupbgitembg").show('fast')
        });
```

Comment: popupbg was a background for it all. I couldnt use it inside because it contained an opacity. Also html buttons exhibit the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

when use Asp.net button in jQuery , you must using class for access this element .
for example :

```
<asp:Button ID="butdelete" calss="butdelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Font-Size="11px"/>
```

because Asp.net , rewriting  element id's during page rendering!
so element id's changing to an other name.
you can see this action with use "view page source " in page right click.

```
<button type="button" ID="butdelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Font-Size="11px"/>
```

In this case , you Not accessing to event manager in asp.net .
perhaps you have need to  use event , but this way maybe not possible?!

For english writing i am sorry , I'm still learning English .
you good luck.